# How can you update a UUID field in a copied JSON string?

Tags: bash, command-line, sed, uuid

I have a JSON string in my paste buffer:

`{ "uuid":"886c69ba-c487-45a9-982e-f22820059a78", "meaningOfLife": 42 }`

I would like to update the UUID to a brand new V4 UUID (random) then overwrite the paste buffer with the new string.  How would I do this in the command line of a Linux/Mac machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved using a combination of a few utilities.

First, come up with a way in the command line to create a new UUID.  There are many ways, one way is installing [gen-uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gen-uuid) after [npm is installed](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/85484771375/how-to-install-npm), e.g. `npm i gen-uuid -g`.  Once this is done, you can run the following code:

```
UUID=`gen-uuid`
pbpaste | sed "s/\"uuid\":\"[^\"]*\"/\"uuid\":\"$UUID\"/g" | pbcopy
```

This will turn

`{ "uuid":"886c69ba-c487-45a9-982e-f22820059a78", "meaningOfLife": 42 }` into something like this:

`{ "uuid":"aab21875-d9d7-4d55-9204-f2d7a9b34109", "meaningOfLife": 42 }`

I prefer to put hairy commands like this in my `~/.bash_profile` file, like so:

```
# overwrite JSON string with a new uuid V4
newu() {
  UUID=`gen-uuid`
  pbpaste | sed "s/\"uuid\":\"[^\"]*\"/\"uuid\":\"$UUID\"/g" | pbcopy
}
```

Then, from your command line, you can run `newu` on any JSON string with a UUID in it!

UPDATE: as noted by @chepner, you can also use the `jq` utility (install on Mac with brew using `brew install jq`) to increase the readability & decrease the brittleness of this `sed` command.  Note that `jq` will throw an error if it is not valid JSON.

```
# overwrite JSON string with a new uuid V4
newu() {
  UUID=`gen-uuid`
  pbpaste | jq --indent 0 ".uuid = \"$UUID\"" | pbcopy
}
```

Comment: If you work with JSON even a *little*, it's worth picking up a tool like `jq`: `pbpaste | jq ".uuid = \"$UUID\"" | pbcopy`.

Comment: @chepner that's a great point, and much more robust.  I didn't know about jq, but I have tried 'jsawk'.  Would you like to make an edit on my answer, or your own answer if it is substantially different?